# Org Charts in sharepoint foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, links

can someone recommend some software for creating and maintaining org charts in SharePoint foundation 2013.

ideally should be free :) easy to edit, and allow picture images to be inserted.

thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

as you are using the foundation so your options are limited, i saw couple of companies offering Org chart for SharePoint Foundations.

[SharePointOrgChart By TeamImprover](https://sharepointorgchart.com/?ref=WN) Free demo but you have to pay for regular use.

[SharePoint Org Chart by Plumsail](https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/)

Comment: Do you know, if we went with the full version of sharepoint server 2013, does that allow for org chart design, to incorporate user pictures etc.

Comment: if you go with SharePoint server then yes Org chart web part is there and you can also create own.SharePoint 2013 Server come with a feature called the "Organisation Browser" to display organisational information. By default the web part is located on every user’s ‘My Profile’ tab on their MySite and it can be added to other pages if required.

Comment: Final question :) would visio 2016 work for creating org charts that can be incorporated into sharepoint 2013 foundation? or is that another unnessary step that could be avoided by moving to the full version?

Comment: I am not sure about the compatibility between office 2016 with sharepoint 2013 foundation. as i haven't tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use Free JQuery plugin to create Organization charts...

All you need to do is pull data from Lists using JSOM or Rest API and Represent the same using Plugin.

You could use one of this plugin and best part is that it is customizable as per your requirement.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart.html

Demo for the same is available on this link:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart/